# auto-dark-theme: error ("Could not determine a viable theme detection mechanism!")

Tags: init-file, themes

After several months of painless use, Emacs suddenly complained when loading the `init.el` file (maybe following updates I could not figure out).

It seems the error is returned by the auto-dark-theme package. Running `emacs --debug-init` shows the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not determine a viable theme detection mecha...")
  signal(error ("Could not determine a viable theme detection mechanism!"))
  error("Could not determine a viable theme detection mecha...")
  auto-dark--determine-detection-method()
  auto-dark-mode(t)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/christophe/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3559
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/christophe/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/christophe/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/christophe/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1579525107bd>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x157952510661>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

The corresponding section in the `init.el` file is this:

```lisp
(setq auto-dark-dark-theme 'nord)
(auto-dark-mode t)
```

Could not find much about how to solve the issue on the web. Could anyone provide me with some hints to solve the issue?

Comment: The error msg is coming from the code that defines that  `auto-dark-theme`. Contact the maintainer of that theme about the problem. Or maybe the theme provides doc that's sufficient to help. In any case, it doesn't look like a general Emacs question, so unless someone here is familiar with that theme and its code you might not find the answer here.